# Last week start date and end date using javascript not giving required result

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code, but it is returning last week's

**start date = 0-4/09/2018** and

**end date = 02/09/2018**

```
var curr = new Date;
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); 
var last = first + 6; 
var startDate = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
var dd1 = startDate.getDate()-6;
var mm1 = startDate.getMonth() + 1;
if(dd1<10){
     dd1='0'+dd1
} 
if(mm1<10){
     mm1='0'+mm1
}
startDate = "" + dd1 + "/" + mm1 + "/" + startDate.getFullYear();
var endDate = new Date(curr.setDate(last));
var dd2 = endDate.getDate()-6;
var mm2 = endDate.getMonth() + 1;
if(dd2<10){
    dd2='0'+dd2
} 
if(mm2<10){
    mm2='0'+mm2
 }
endDate = "" + dd2 + "/" + mm2 + "/" + endDate.getFullYear();
```

Comment: How is the question related to `php`. Assuming this is all about javascript, what exactly are you trying to achieve? first day and last day of last week of the current month? Does the week need to have all week days or it can roll over to next month? Unless you explain what is it that you are attempting to do, it's impossible to find the problem or offer an appropriate solution

Comment: Did you consider using `moment.js`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Date object and set its date to the value you like before getting the value. Your implementation is not valid because:

- Type casting missing
- you cannot perform Date().getDate()-6, if the date is 1 you will calculate negative value, so no sense for date.

The correct form is that:

```
var curr,startDate,endDate, strStartDate,strEndDate;
curr = new Date();
curr.setDate(curr.getDate()+6)

startDate = new Date(curr.getTime());
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()-6)

strStartDate = startDate.getDate()+"/"+(startDate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+startDate.getFullYear();


endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime());
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()-6);

strEndDate = endDate.getDate()+"/"+(endDate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+endDate.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

With a recommendation to use [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/) for date/time manipulation, I offer a solution based on it.

```
let startDate = moment().endOf("month").startOf("isoWeek");    // Also, check .startOf("week");
let endDate = moment().endOf("month").endOf("isoWeek");    // Also, check .endOf("week");
console.log(start);    // moment object
console.log(start.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));    // date string
console.log(end);    // moment object
console.log(end.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));    // date string
```